# Comboboxes do not select given value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 comboboxes and I want to select a specific item by specifying a value using JS but they don't seem to work.

these are the Comboboxes:

```
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                            <label for="email"> Estado:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="Estado" name="cbmEstado" required> 
                            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                            <option value="1">Activo</option>
                            <option value="0">Inactivo</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                            <label for="email"> Exonerado:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="Exonerado" name="cbmExonerado" required> 
                            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                            <option value="1">Sí</option>
                            <option value="0">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

this is the code to select the item in the Combobox:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('Exonerado').value =1;
    document.getElementById('Estado').value =1;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try putting the `1` in quotes `.value = "1"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome seems to do exactly what you wanted. But I suspect that the real problem here is that you pass a `Number` and not a `String`.

If you wrap them in quotes like in the following code snippet, it works like a charm.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('Exonerado').value = "1";
  document.getElementById('Estado').value = "0";
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <label for="email"> Estado:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="Estado" name="cbmEstado" required>
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
      <option value="1">Activo</option>
      <option value="0">Inactivo</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <label for="email"> Exonerado:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="Exonerado" name="cbmExonerado" required>
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
      <option value="1">Sí</option>
      <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('Exonerado').value = "1";
  document.getElementById('Estado').value = "1";
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <label for="email"> Estado:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="Estado" name="cbmEstado" required>
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
      <option value="1">Activo</option>
      <option value="0">Inactivo</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <label for="email"> Exonerado:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="Exonerado" name="cbmExonerado" required>
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
      <option value="1">Sí</option>
      <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now this will help you out from your query

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the code so far, it should work without any problem.